# To download and install boost library 1.46 On fedora 12

Tags: boost, fedora

I need to install boost lib 1.46 on my Target machine which has Fedora 12. But its not connected to internet. I have development machine running Ubuntu and is connected to internet.

Target machine can received files from ubuntu machine.  Could someone please advise me how to download Boost library 1.46 compatible to fedora 12 and where to copy in Target machine and how to compile and built. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an i386 machine, you can download the RPM package from [here](http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/12/Fedora/i386/os/Packages/)

Look for packages starting with 'boost'. The main one is

```
boost-1.39.0-8.fc12.i686.rpm
```

but you might also need one or more of these (in particular `boost-devel`):

```
boost-date-time-1.39.0-8.fc12.i686.rpm
boost-devel-1.39.0-8.fc12.i686.rpm
boost-filesystem-1.39.0-8.fc12.i686.rpm
boost-graph-1.39.0-8.fc12.i686.rpm
boost-iostreams-1.39.0-8.fc12.i686.rpm
boost-math-1.39.0-8.fc12.i686.rpm
boost-program-options-1.39.0-8.fc12.i686.rpm
boost-python-1.39.0-8.fc12.i686.rpm
boost-regex-1.39.0-8.fc12.i686.rpm
boost-serialization-1.39.0-8.fc12.i686.rpm
boost-signals-1.39.0-8.fc12.i686.rpm
boost-system-1.39.0-8.fc12.i686.rpm
boost-test-1.39.0-8.fc12.i686.rpm
boost-thread-1.39.0-8.fc12.i686.rpm
boost-wave-1.39.0-8.fc12.i686.rpm
```

Copy the RPMs you need to the target machine, and as root do

```
rpm -ivh <package.rpm>
```

for the package you want to install. It might tell you that dependency packages are missing, in which case you need to copy the corresponding dependency RPMs to the target machine as well, and use the command above (as root) to install them.

If the target machine is a 64 bit one, and you want to install 64 bit libraries, get the RPMs from [here](http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/12/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/) instead.